# Azure DevOps YAML NuGetCommand@2 - Specify MSBuildVersion or MSBuildPath

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

We are making use of the YAML Build pipeline task NuGetCommand@2

We are restoring 1 or more solutions with this task.

There is a need to configure the MSBuild path into NuGet, which is possible via the CLI, but in the [NuGetCommand documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops) there is no such option.

Is there perhaps a hidden feature that makes this possible? Or should i convert the task to a custom action, which makes it a lot more difficult?